# ios crash in 'NSCFString dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:]: didn't convert all characters'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to convert NSString to NSData with following code:

```
NSUInteger lengthTest = contentStr.length;
NSStringEncoding encodingStr = CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingGB_18030_2000);
if ([contentStr canBeConvertedToEncoding:encodingStr]) {
    NSData *data = [contentStr dataUsingEncoding:encodingStr allowLossyConversion:YES];
    lengthTest = [data length];
}
```

But my fabric report a Crash named: NSCFString dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:]: didn't convert all characters'
I want to know which character could cause this problem and fix it , expecting someone could help me.

Comment: Why is this tagged with [swift] ?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example of a string causing this problem?

Comment: According to https://github.com/sequelpro/sequelpro/issues/2451 this might happen when Memory corruption or OS BUG